# Why am I getting random errors all of a sudden in Xcode when I don't think I changed anything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build

All of a sudden I am getting crazy random errors when I build my project in Xcode. There are usually around 15 or 16 errors that appear, but they all relate to a 3rd party library, not my own code.

First it was the `FMDB` library that had all the errors, then randomly later on it was `ASIHttp` errors, same kind of messages, such as:

`Illegal interface qualifier`

Then there are lots of `Expected a type` errors is a few of the headers, e.g.

```
- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders;
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL;
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestRedirected:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

All of the above lines error.

The only warning I have is to do with my own code, which is:

`Incomplete implementation` however it seems to me like it is complete, there is nothing missing from the class that I have in the header.

It's totally blowing my mind, I have no idea what's wrong, so if anybody could help I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you cleaned the build and restarted XCode?

Comment: Just tried both of those now, still failing :(

Comment: Please show more detail; it looks like the compiler hasn't been introduced to the `ASIHTTPRequest` class...

Comment: `ASIHttp` has worked fine in the past, just an hour ago, everything was building with no errors or warnings. It's been working alright for weeks.

Comment: @HarryLawrence I had this kind of errors once (`Illegal interface qualifier`) amongst others. And without knowing it, I had typed an extra character near the beginning of a header file. All of a sudden, near 60 errors did appear in all the files included below the extra character. Unfortunately, Xcode did not report the extra character as an error. I had a hard time finding it. Removing it solved all errors. Maybe you could check for that. If it works, I will turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: If you're using git, I would just look at the file modification history and see if you accidentally changed anything.

Comment: I'll try checking for typos now.

Comment: The fact that I suddenly have an `Incomplete implementation` in one of my classes, when infact it seems to be complete; does that ring any alarm bells for anyone?

Comment: Usually you can click on an `Incomplete implementation` warning to drill down to where the problem lies - might help

Comment: sounds like a typo somewhere to drive one crazy.

Comment: Another part of my 'fix xcode doing stupid stuff' process is to open Organizer and 'delete derived data' for the the project. Fixes 95% of issues...

Comment: @Jean you were more or less correct in that it was a typo issue with a header file. I went looking for it, and eventually fixed it. Post as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @HarryLawrence I did write the answer. Please, could you provide additional details on `you were more or less correct` so that I can improve the answer for others (I am also personally interested, because this error was one of the hardest I ever had to to find. None of the error messages were useful or made any sense to me. I spent a day on it, eventually re-creating a new project and importing files one-by-one before noticing the extra characters).

Comment: It's kinda embarrassing to be honest, it had been a long day, and I just didn't spot it, but I had at some point accidentally deleted `@end` from the header file. The point is, if there were to be a typo in the header file, or in my case missing the `@end`, is gives errors that make it very hard to debug as they are essentially irrelevant to to typo/problem itself. That's really the main point I'd make in terms of explaining this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this kind of errors once (`Illegal interface qualifier`) amongst others.

**Symptoms**

Large amount of errors appearing out of the blue in previously perfectly compilable projects.
Error are most often syntax- or qualifier-related. The code looks fine, the symbols are well defined, the method exists, but somehow the compiler sees an error.
The errors can also pop near function-ends, Objective-C message ends, control loop ends, etc.

**Cause of the issue**

The presence of an extra character near the beginning of a header or code file. Unknowingly added by the developer.

**How to solve it**

Checking headers and source files. Looking for ill-placed characters, especially near the beginning of the files.

Comment: Just a heads up, this also happened to me when I accidentally omitted an `@end` when I was copy/pasting some files.